# GWT ImageSprite: how to move the background image to the right side

Tags: css, gwt, css-sprites, cssresource, clientbundle

I want to use the following style in GWT client bundle:

`.myClass tr:hover {

    background: url("myImage.png") 185px 2px no-repeat;

}`

I declared the image as follows:

`@Source("resources/myImage.png")

@ImageOptions(repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.None)

ImageResource myImage();`

and changes the style to:

`@sprite .myClass tr:hover {

    gwt-image: "myImage";

    background-position: 185px 2px;

}`

But it does not work. There are several images in the generated XYZ.cache.png. So if I change the background-position in firebug I see the complete image bundle.

How can I move the background image to the right position?

Comment: Does it provide `pseudo-classes` ?! I think, you should set OnHover/ OnOut listeners...

Answer (score 1):

```
@sprite .myClass tr:hover {
    gwt-image: "myImage";
}

div.myClass tr:hover{
    background-position: 185px 2px; 
}
```

As you noticed, gwt-image will be default remove 'background-position' along with some other ones. To override the default position of `0 0`, add a more specific css rule with the position you desire.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't affect anything. The whole image bundle is placed on left side. I tryed to change width, height und background-position in firebug but the image seems to have the width of the tr element.

Comment: You can try to use background-position: right; in the .myClass tr:hover

Answer (score 1):

The generated width property of ImageSprite does not work because the width of tr element is fix. It is better zu create a td with an image element (as ImageResource) on the right side of table row. CSS looks like:

```
 <code>
    div.myClass img {
      visibility: hidden;
    }

div.myClass tr:hover img {
  visibility: visible;
}

</code>
```

So solution assumes there are no more images in the table.